# Python library difference?

Tags: python, python-2.7, shared-libraries

If I run

```
bob@me:/usr$ find . -name 'libpython2.7.so'
```

I get two hits:

```
./lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so
./lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so
```

What's the difference?

Answer (score 3):

One is the configuration for the libpython2.7.so while the other is the exact location where the files for that particular library reside.

Comment: Ok, so if I wanted to reference it, say in wanting to install another package; which one should I link to? The second presumably?

Comment: @Astrid yes. you should.

Comment: And what is the difference between `libpyton2.7.so` and `libpyton2.7.so.1.0`?. Running `diff libpython2.7.so libpython2.7.so.1.0` nought.